# Extrude along normals issue

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is there way to avoid Blender doing this? Using Extrude Region (Vertex normals) or Extrude and than <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> does the same thing. Is there any chance this could be improved in case this is how it suppose to work?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

When operating <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>, you can enable *Even Thickness* mode by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> or pressing <kbd>S</kbd> once (see the tip on the 3D View header).

[image]